# SSRS New page per selected Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, grouping

I have a report which uses 3 datasets and on the report a am using Multiple Tables and Textboxes and expressions. When I run the report I have to select a Parameter which in this example is 'City'.

I want a new page for each City (parameter) , I have read to use page breaks and grouping but I selected a List from the toolbox and put that on top of my report, selected 2 'Cities' and expected it to return 2 pages but it returned 49 pages (majority blank)

I want a separate page per city how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (it difficult to be sure if you don't post your current design) then you would be better using subreports.

I'm assuming Cities are in a table in your database and each have a unique ID. If you only have the names then you can use `CityName` inplace of `CityID` and it will still work.

Create a new report.
Create new dataset (say `dsSelectedCities` and the set dataset query to something like ...

```
SELECT CityID, CityName FROM myCitiesTable WHERE CityID IN (@CityParameter)
```

This will automatically generate a report parameter called `@CityParameter`. Set the available values etc just the way you did in your original report, so if you need to add another dataset for this then do so. In this example I've assumed labels will be `CityName` and Values will be `CityID`. Whatever goes into the Values is what will be passed to our subreport.

Now add a table to you report, it only needs to be one column wide and one row long so just remove any other rows and columns just make sure you leave the detail row and not the header.

Set the dataset for the table to be `dsSelectedCities`

Make this remaining cell with wide enough to accommodate your subreport (which will be the report you originally wrote).

In the cell, insert a subreport
Set the subreport properties to point to your original report and set the parameter to the `CityID` **field**.

This table will act as a loop, for each record found in `dsSelectedCities` it will give us one row. As each row will have a single `CityID` we are passing that to the subreport, the subreport in turn just shows one City.

Set the page break option on the details group to break between instances.

You will probably have to modify your original report to accept a single CityID, it depends on how it was designed but hopefully this should get you going.

If this is unclear then post your current report design including all the details about parameters and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi I will give that a go one question in my report I already have a dataset for the cities.  These are basically records on the database. Do I retain the dataset in this original report even though I am creating it again for the new report?

Comment: What I would suggest is making a copy of your original report, remove any parameter settings that relate to default or available values and then see if the dataset is still required. Any datasets that are used purely to populate parameters will almost certainly be redundant and should be removed as these just slow the report processing down for no reason. You should be in a position where you can run the report (the subreport) by typing the CityID into the city parameter and it gives you what you want for a single city.

Comment: I am struggling with this subreport. I created a new report as you mentioned and created a dataset with the cityname and cityid. On the parameter I have set 'Allow multiple values' and for available values I have selected the dataset and chosen the cityname field. On the subreport parameter I set the parameter to the cityid field. When i run the report i get 'One or more parameters were not specified for the subreport'. ANy ideas?